# Converting Python code to pyspark environment

Tags: pandas, pyspark, group-by, shift, cumsum

How can I have the same functions as shift() and cumsum() from pandas in pyspark?

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a',0],['a',0],['a',0],['b',0],['b',1],['b',1],['c',1],['c',0],['c',0]], columns=['ID','X'])

temp['transformed'] = temp.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: (x["X"].shift() != x["X"]).cumsum()).reset_index()['X']
print(temp)
```

My question is how to achieve in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark have handle these type of queries with Windows utility functions.
you can read its documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html)

Your pyspark code would be something like this :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql Import Window as W
window = W.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time'?)
new_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('shifted', F.lag('X').over(window))
    .withColumn('isEqualToPrev', (F.col('shifted') == F.col('X')).cast('int'))
    .withColumn('cumsum', F.sum('isEqualToPrev').over(window))
)
```

Comment: I just fixed my answer code, i think its more useful to you :)
its better to ask your question like this:
how I can have same function as shift or cumsum from pandas in pyspark?
people with same problem as you can find their answer in your question if you have a nice description